# OnItemClickListener listview

Tags: android

I have one problem in getting the selected string from the ListItems for Eg: consider my ListItem has some elements just consider as one,two,three is present in my taskLit,now if i click on the ListItem i,e on One,Two or Three i should get that Particular String value.Is there any possibility to get the Selected String value from the ListItems or Is there any method like getSelectedStringItem().Thanks in advance.

```
public void taskOverview()
    {       
        List<TaskList> taskList = new ArrayList<TaskList>();

        taskList.add(new TaskList("OutStanding:", true, false));
        taskList.add(new TaskList(">>"+TaskList.getOutStandingTask(), false,true));

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.taskList);
        listView.setClickable(true);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewTaskActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        TaskListAdapter taskListAdapter = new TaskListAdapter(this, taskList);
        listView.setAdapter(taskListAdapter);
        taskListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: you should give some code example or be more specific about the class names, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), mListItems.get(position), 1000).show();
    }

});
```